# Couldnt read the video that is captured by JMF framework

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, jmf

I used JMF framework to capture the video from a web cam and storing it to the local directory as ".mov" file. I couldnt play the stored video in other machines, where as I can play the video in my machine.

I can play it in VLC player in other machines, where as I couldnt play it in Windows media player.

My intention here is to process the video generated by JMF framework in opencv.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a windows media player vlc codec pack on whatever machines can't play it.

If the opencv is in Java then you might be interested in vlcj from http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/index.html.